# Batch copy/paste of rectangular images in square images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, indesign-scripting

I have got more than 1000 rectangular images (640x400) with a transparent background that I want to resize (to 600x375) and then copy/paste (centered) in a 600x600 transparent image.

In other words, I want to create 1000 600x600 square images from 1000 640x400 rectangular images without deforming what is drawn in the rectangular image.

Any idea about how to do that ?

Thanks !!!!

Comment: I do not have time for a long answer right now, but with that many, you want to look into _ImageMagick_. You would - with the right command - be able to do the whole thing in one go, at the most two. And no fiddling with (and this is the less good option 2) actions in Photoshop.

Comment: If you can tell me what is the exact procedure to follow with this tool, it would be great ! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

In Photoshop the easiest way is to make an action and then run a batch. First step is to change image size to desired and then change canvas size to 600.

Illustrator don't allow to record an action with artboard resize but you can do it with macros but you would still need to open every file manually and then start the macro.